# Using LINQ add CHILD VALUE always 1

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, submitchanges

I have the Tables

**PatientEligibilit**
 and 
**PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialties**
and 
**DoctorsSpecialties**

**PatientEligibilit**
has foreign key  ***PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialtyID***  from 
**PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialties**
table

and

**PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialty**
has foreign key  ***DoctorsSpecialtyID***  from 
**DoctorsSpecialties**
table

**THEN USING VB.NET LINQ:** i'm tring to add child item ( ***PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialty***)
to it's parent (**PatientEligibilit**)

then I submit Changes

like :

```
PatientEligibilityObject.PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialties.Add(New PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialty With {.DoctorSpecialtyID = si.ID, .RegDate = Date.Now})                                                                            PatientEligibilityObject.PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialties.Add(PEDS)
HMSData.SubmitChanges()
```

it's worked fine and save record in Database with correct date

**BUT**

```
DoctorSpecialtyID
```

always saved with value `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. the problem was in the relation between the tables.

The foreign key between  **PatientEligibilit** and **PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialties**
was not correct..